# FB Comments loaded via ajax div

Tags: ajax, facebook, prototypejs, facebook-comments

Here's my issue, I'm trying to load a FB comments module via an AJAX div. Now, it works if I go directly to the php page, but if I load it from within the div, it doesn't. I've looked at the other posts ([FB javascript SDK after jquery LOAD (ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373220/fb-javascript-sdk-after-jquery-load-ajax)), but still can't seem to get it to work, looking for clarification.

If you want to see what I'm talking about, check http://azconceptphoto.com/lindsey and check out testimonials.

Ideally, on the normal part of my site, I can just load the HTML5 code and it works fine, though for some reason it doesn't remotely work via the AJAX div. And considering the posts from before are out of date (2011), I was hoping to get more feedback on this.

Comment: Are you calling FB.XFBML.parse() after loading the <fb:comments> element into your DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from your link you are not using any of the PrototypeJS `Ajax` methods to get the backend script. `Ajax.Updater` is the method you need to use so....

Here is my suggestion

change the definition of `loadXMLDoc()` to

```
function loadXMLDoc(div, location)
{
    new Ajax.Updater(div,location,{'evalScripts':true});
}
```

this will update the contents of `div` with the contents of `location`. Also if the response has `<script>` tags in it then the javascript will be parsed and evaluated (thats the option `evalScripts`)